# IDisposable Interface

Tags: c#

I know about `IDisposable` Interface and it's use in .net but there is a question in my mind that If i am writing all managed code , does implementing `IDisposable` interface make any sense?

i know when and how to use Idisposible but my question is if i am writing all managed code say a simple class nothing expensive in it so if i implement `IDisposable` in this class and do some cleanup like freeing some global values, Does it make some sense?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "freeing some global values"? If they're global then they're not a part of the object, so it an object shouldn't "dispose" of them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, you may not need to use IDisposble interface. However, it's recommended under certain circumstances (I might add later more as I remember :) ):

1. You class has many objects and there are of lots of cross references. Even though its all managed, GC may not be able to reclaim the memory due to alive references. You get a chance (other than writing a finalizer) to untangle the references and break up the links the way you attached them. Hence, you are helping the GC to reclaim the memory.
2. You have some streams open which are alive till the object of the class dies. Even though such implementations of files/network etc are managed, they go deep down to handles in Win32 mode. Hence, you get a chance to write a `Dispose` method where you can close the streams. The same is true for GDI objects, and some more.
3. You are writing a class which uses unmanaged resources, and you want to ship your assembly to third parties. You better use disposable pattern to make sure you are able to free the handles to avoid the leakage.
4. Thanks to supercat for this: Your class implements lots of event handlers and hooks them up to events. The objects of classes which expose the events, like `Form` etc., will not be freed up by GC since the implementations local to your class (maybe) are still hooked into those events. You can unhook those event handlers in `Dispose`; again helping GC.

Hmm... I can't remember more right now, but if the class is complex in its behaviours, you might want to rethink why you don't want implement `IDisposable` interface.

Comment: I'd amend #4: your class implements **ANY** event handlers for objects which may exist outside your class.

Answer (score 7):

Rule of thumb: you need to implement IDisposable if your type has a member variable that is itself IDisposable or if it is unmanaged. GC is non-deterministic in .NET and IDisposable gives you a deterministic way not to reclaim memory but to reclaim *resources*. So when Dispose() is invoke, your memory is not immediately freed by the GC but you can clean up unmanaged *resources* deterministically (e.g., ensure your database connections are closed and you don't max connections on the server).

Comment: The GC will never free unmanaged resources unless it is told to, usually be calling `Dispose()` in a finalizer. The GC has no knowledge unmanaged resources even exist.

Comment: @Matt - Yep, totally agree that GC has no knowledge of unmanaged resources - wasn't implying anything different. Just saying that developer knows if the resource is unmanaged and can take action appropriately.

Comment: "resources" is not only unmanaged handles, connections or files. Your huge hashtable or set of subscribed clients through events are resources too. It not recommended to provide deterministic way to release managed resources in .NET, but if you are sure you need it -- why not to use IDisposable?

Comment: @Dmitry - For managed objects, yes, non-deterministic is perfectly fine (if that managed object does not own any unmanaged resources) as my answer reflects.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a resource that needs to be reclaimed (like File) you want to have IDisposible in order to explicitly close it and not wait for the GC todo it.

Comment: This is especially important for classes that manage data connectors. Leaving unclosed data connectors after a class has gone to the GC is bad juju.

Comment: i know when and how to use Idisposible but my question is if i am writing all managed code say a simple class nothing expensive in it so if i implement Idisposible in this class and do some cleanup like freeing some global values, Does it make some sense?

Comment: IDisposable is just an interface and some syntactic sugar provided by C#. 
If you think you need to implement it, that's useful for your particular case -- do it; i see no problems. IMHO.

Answer (score 3):

A seldom-mentioned scenario where proper use of iDisposable is *critical* is an object with a short useful life that receives events from a long-lived object.  The Dispose method for such an object must unsubscribe its events.  If the object does not unsubscribe itself, it will not be eligible for garbage-collection until the object(s) whose events it has subscribed become eligible for garbage collection; that may very well be never.

For example, some types of enumerator need to subscribe to "object changed" messages.  It would be entirely plausible for many thousands of such enumerators to be created during the execution of a long-running program.  If such enumerators were not unsubscribed, they could effectively clog the system, even if they never use any resources other than managed memory.

Note, btw, that despite the importance of disposing of such an object, adding a finalizer to ensure such disposal would be useless.  If an event publisher has gone out of scope, attempting to unsubscribing from one of its events would be at best useless and possibly dangerous.  Since an event subscriber can't go out of scope unless the publishers of all the events it receives have also gone out of scope, the finalizer would only get called after there was nothing left for it to do.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, even when you do not have any managed resources around, `IDisposable` can still be helpful. Why? Because you can use the `Dispose` method to reset object references back to `null`.

Note that this by itself doesn't yet free any resources, since garbage collection is non-deterministic (ie. it doesn't normally run at any moment of your choosing), BUT it breaks up references (links) between objects, making it more probable that some objects will be eligible for garbage collection on the GC's next run.

Comment: Stakx... personal observation: setting objects to null is not really good always. You don't really need to set objects to null unless there are lots of cross references. In other times, there are objects which are pushed to older generations which kick in when set to null and interfere with quick disposal. However, you are free to disagree :)

Comment: @Nayan, thanks for sharing that bit of knowledge. I see no reason to disagree. On the other hand, I haven't so far had any bad experiences with disposing early rather than late, and I think it makes for a good *general* guideline: once something's no longer used, let it go. By using `IDisposable` -- even when it's not strictly necessary -- you can state that intent explicitly. (Of course on shouldn't exaggerate by applying the guideline absolutely everywhere.)

Comment: Yes, you are right. As a general guideline, implementation of IDisposable should be there. But I'd like to mention two things: 1st) I was talking about setting objects to null and wasn't disagreeing on using IDisposable... 2nd) This general guideline has to be scrutinized critically when using objects which sit on LOH. Frequent allocation and de-allocation may create memory fragmentation in LOH.

Answer (score 0):

Does it make some sense?

No, make your object disposable only if it is expensive to create.

Comment: That's not why one would make an object disposable. You make is disposable if it deals with resources that are not managed by .NET in the same way that memory is, e.g. TCP sockets

Comment: You are not correct, of course one could and should implement the disposable patter on managed .net classes.