# What is the proper way to use IDisposable?

Tags: c#, dispose

In the example below...  Since the class have an IDisposable interface and the class is itself is only a manage memory objects (not an unmanaged memory), so in the script further down below (See case #1 and case #2) - what is the proper way to do Disposal when done w/ the list objects?

```
 public class VehicleA : IDisposable
 {
     public void Dispose() { }

     public string Year {get;set;}
     public string Make {get;set;}
     public string Model {get;set;}
 }
 public class repositoryVehicle()
 {
     public List<VehicleA> VehicleLookup()
     {
         List<VehicleA> returnVehicles = new List<Vehicle>();

         returnVehicles.Add(new VehicleA { Year="2007", Make="Ford", Model="Mustang" });
         returnVehicles.Add(new VehicleA { Year="2004", Make="Chevy", Model="Blazer" });

         return returnVehicles;
     }
 }

 //Case #1...
 foreach(var v in repositoryVehicle.VehicleLookup())
 {
     //v.Year...
 }

 //Case #2...
 List<VehicleA> vehicles = new List<VehicleA>();
 vehicles = repositoryVehicle.VehicleLookup();
 //vehicles[x].Year...
```

Comment: If your class doesn't have anything that needs special cleanup, why have it implement IDisposable?

Comment: Possibly relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/538060/proper-use-of-the-idisposable-interface

Comment: take a look at this SO Q&A on [when to use IDisposable with managed resources](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3908463/idisposable-interface)

Comment: What @nekizalb said: unless you're connecting to a DB, or doing something that's not going to be quickly and automatically de-allocated or closed, there's no real reason to implement IDisposable.

Comment: Your classes do not need `IDisposable`. If this was meant as pseude ocode you'll have to highlight that and the actual question better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dispose pattern is used only for objects that access unmanaged resources. This is because the garbage collector is very efficient at reclaiming unused managed objects.

> There is no performance benefit in implementing the Dispose method on
>   types that use only managed resources (such as arrays) because they
>   are automatically reclaimed by the garbage collector. Use the Dispose
>   method primarily on managed objects that use native resources and on
>   COM objects that are exposed to the .NET Framework. Managed objects
>   that use native resources (such as the FileStream class) implement the
>   IDisposable interface.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs2xkftw.aspx

Comment: Array and  `List<>` are not managed resources. They're just memory.

Comment: "*This is because the garbage collector is very efficient at reclaiming unused managed objects.*" I'd like to qualify that. GC is efficient only if there is enough memory. For example see here: http://sealedabstract.com/rants/why-mobile-web-apps-are-slow/

Comment: *"The dispose pattern is used only for objects that access unmanaged resources"* - I've also used `IDisposable` to make sure events are correctly unsubscribed to, or else they could cause memory leaks.  I consider that a design-flaw with events, though - events subscriptions *should* be a weak-reference.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft yes, this is certainly a relevant point. I'm not sure that event subscribtion *should* be weak-reference, but it's true that if you subscribe to something and let the subscriber go the memory won't be reclaimed as the subscriber will continue processing events.

Comment: @zespri: ...that article *(from your first comment)* is about JS garbage collection in various browsers, which has absolutely nothing to do with this question or answer...

Comment: @zespri: (re: second comment) I am talking about the event publisher not being reclaimed, despite the fact that it will never publish any more events.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft, no, it's not the case. a) GC in general have the same principles JS or not, and more importantly b) the article also talks about .net on mobile devices.

Comment: Mr BlueRaja...pls read the article from Microsoft. I am sure it will clear all your queries.

Comment: @Purshpendra - "Use the Dispose method primarily on managed objects that use native resources".  In other word, you're trying to say like this...  FileStream.Dispose();  Right?

Comment: If anything that is Managed object will be dealt by GC and you need to implement Disposable when and only when you have anything that is unmanaged object.